# Maintaining a Relative Order of Flex Tasks in a SQL DB

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, relational-database

I have a task scheduling app that allows people to create 2 types of tasks...

•Strict- tasks with a set start time and duration 
•Flex- tasks that have a duration, but no specific start time

Its also important to understand how flex tasks operate- Flex tasks will continuously reschedule themselves throughout your day in the nearest time you have open...so for example if the only task on your schedule today is a flex task like  "Go workout - duration:60mins" and you open the app at 4pm it will have "Go workout" scheduled from 4-5pm for you , if you dont click the checkbox indicating you completed the task and open the app again at 5PM "Go workout will be rescheduled to 5-6pm so that the stuff you are meaning to get done is constantly in your face and trying to fit itself into the gaps of your life.

When a user views their schedule here are the steps I go through:
•Grab a array of all strict tasks 
•Grab a array of all flex tasks 
•Loop through each strict task and figure out how big of a time gap there is between the task currently being looped's end time  and the next tasks start time.
•if a gap exists loop through the flex tasks and see if any of them will fit in the time gap in question. if a flex task is small enough to fit in the time gap add it to the strictTasksArray between the task being currently looped and the next task.

This works great as long as there is no need for any kind of ordering when it comes to flex tasks, but now we have added the ability for users to drag and drop flex tasks into a specific relative order aka  if  I have  Task A,B,C,D
and I drag Task D & B to the front so that its now D,B,A,C  it needs to save that ordering so that if you close and reopen the app the app will still remember to try to fit task D  in  , followed by B, A & C .....but im having big trouble thinking of a efficient way to do considering the ordering is relative and not strict...any ideas how to save relative ordering in a SQLIte DB without having to update every tasks's DB record every time a user drag/drops a task and changes the relative ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you'd need some sort of either `priority` or `order_number` column to set the order in which the tasks come in. Just make it an int, and weight them accordingly. If you needed the DBMS to keep them in order using a query, you'd have to use sorting:

```
SELECT task_id, task_group_id, task_name, completed, priority 
FROM tasks WHERE user = ? and task_group_id = ? and completed = 0 ORDER BY priority ASC
```

you can use some sort of foreign key to a task_group table to actually group certain tasks together if they're multipart, and then build a query to find all the ones that are either complete or incomplete. The weightage assigned would still be correct, because the tasks don't refer to each other by ID.

Comment: In a app where a user could have dozens or 100s of task you sure it makes sense to be running as many update queries as there are flex tasks every time a user drags and drops a task in real time?

Comment: Make the priority a decimal, and simply reorder one item using the number exactly in-between the priorities you're inserting. The user would have to reorder a nearly impossible number of times to hit the limit of this

Comment: Once you did hit the limit, do what Y.B. said and do one job of doing a recalculation of all the priorities in that group of tasks back to whole numbers. Would be a once-in-every-great-while mass update

Answer (score 1):

If you have ever coded in Basic, you might remember numbering code lines. It was advisable to number in increments of 10 so that if later on you would have to insert a line or two you won't have to re-number all the code, just assign a new number in-between those of the previous and the next lines.

So, in your situation I would create a numeric field for Rank and for each new Flex task assign Rank = max(Rank) + 1024 (for example). Afterwards if the tasks are rearranged I would update just one "moved" task's Rank with the average Rank of it's new previous and next neighbours. That way any Rank change would be an update for one row only. Of cause if the Rank is `int` and I run out of integers in-between two tasks I would have to update them all, but that should be a rear occasion and I would just re-Rank them in new increments of 1024.